# Chart.js custom plugin before destroy

Tags: chart.js

I have to manually destroy my chart instance by calling `this.chart.destroy();` My problem is that I have a custom plugin which has event listeners. When a chart is destroyed, it notifies the plugins, and in the plugin's destroy call I call `chart.canvas.removeEventListener()`. But this works only for the automatic destroy, and when I call destroy manually, the canvas stops existing before the plugins are notified. As far as I could find, there are no events that are run before destroy, according to the [documents](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.4.1/api/interfaces/plugin.html) stop and uninstall are also called after destroy.

Is there a way to have an event before destroying chart? Or is the only way to handle it to do it outside the plugin, for example uninstalling the plugin manually? If the latter, I think it is a bug.

Chart.js version: 3.5.1
Edit: doesn't work also for version 3.6.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make a [workaround](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hra57y?file=src/app/hello.component.ts) by placing the event listener removers to reset, and doing `this.chart.notifyPlugins('reset')` before `this.chart.destroy()`, so I can check `if (chart.canvas)` on plugin destroy. This is however just a workaround and I should not have to rely on manual removing, so I filed a [bug ticket](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/9931) too.